# printing with the python library brother_ql on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian

I am trying to use the python library brother_ql to print to an brother_ql700 from a raspberry pi. It is supposed to bypass any driver and send serial commands to the printer thru the usb port (so no need to install any driver):

```
cat command.bin > /dev/usb/lp1
```

My problem is that I do not see any /dev/usb/lp1 port. I suspect that this is the port for most versions of Linux but that it may be different for the Raspian.

I checked the devices with:

```
ls -la /dev
```

I tried to send the command to /dev/tty or /dev/tty0 but with no success..
I made sure that my user what added to the group of the tty that owns the tty ports and that group members had the right of write....

Any idea how I can figure out the port ? Or is there any config to add to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the author of the brother_ql Python package, I can say that the QL-700 is working perfectly on the Raspberry Pi.

The most probable issue is that your label printer is in the so-called "Editor Lite" mode, where it shows up as a USB storage device.

To cite the readme of the package:

> Note: If your printer has an 'Editor Lite' mode, you need to disable it if you want to print via USB. Make sure that the corresponding LED is not lit by holding the button down until it turns off.

`lsusb | grep Brother` helps you identify in which mode your device is connected.

```
# when in Editor Lite mode:
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04f9:2049 Brother Industries, Ltd
# when in the correct mode:
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 04f9:2042 Brother Industries, Ltd
```

Comment: Thank you for this great library and for spotting my mistake: the cause was to not disable the 'Editor Lite' on the printer. It works with no other configuration than adding the user to the 'lp' group.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that selecting the wrong format size will cause an error.